# Shorten Time PHP Variable

Tags: php, string, numbers, substring

I have a variable `$var1` which is set to: `-7:00` and I need to shorten it to `-7`.

Store this new variable in `$var2`. I tried:

```
$var2 = substr($var1, -2);
```

But I just ended up with `00`.

Comment: Have a look at the docs for `substr()` and you will understand the behavior: http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Comment: So where are we with this question ?

Answer (score 2):

Just cast your variable to an integer, so that it gets cut off if a non numerical value is hit:

```
echo $var2 = (int) $var1;
```

output:

```
-7
```

Comment: Also you can use this syntax for this: `$var1 = intval($var1);`

Comment: @RichardReiber Too much to type :)

Comment: Yes, but if you only want to work with one syntax ;-) This can be clearer if you concat many functions :-)

Comment: @RichardReiber inquirer said need to `$var2` :) Then `$var2 = intval($var1);`

Comment: @Fatemeh thank you for information. I have changed it in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$var2 = substr($var1, 0, -3);
```

or

```
$var2 = rtrim($var1, ":0");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$var1 = "-7:00";
$var2 = substr($var1, 0, -3);
//or $var2 = substr($var1,0,2);
echo $var2;
// -7
```

---

> string substr ( string $string , int $start [, int $length ] )

Learn more about http://php.net/substr

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use substr():

```
$Var2 = substr($Var1,0,2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize now that there are multiple ways of accomplishing this.
I just decided to go with the method below.

```
$var2 = intval($var1);
echo "Words: ";
echo $var2;
```